# TextStyle behaves different in Text and TextField

Tags: flutter

I want to create an input field with a smooth transition from edit to view state. This requires me to have the same text style for the Text and the TextField. However, when switching state, the size is not the same. This is very visible in the layout shift.

I have already tried to recreate this problem with a new project, it still occurs there as well.

Code from Project:

```
 child: (editableTask.taskState == TaskState.view)
                ? Container(
                    color: Colors.red,
                    child: Text(
                      editableTask.nameController.value.text,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                      textScaler: TextScaler.noScaling,
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      autofocus: editableTask.taskState == TaskState.create
                          ? true
                          : false,
                      controller: editableTask.nameController,
                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                      maxLines: null,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        isCollapsed: true,
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        hintText: 'Add name ...',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```

[image: gif that shows change in size and style]

Using Flutter v 3.16.2

Comment: You could try using the same `TextFormField` and change from disabled to enabled when editing starts.

Comment: Thanks for the input! i will have to add a color to the `TextStyle` property to have no visual changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
        color: _isEditing ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: _isEditing
            ? TextFormField(
                controller: _controller,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  isCollapsed: true,
                  border: InputBorder.none,
                  hintText: 'Add name ...',
                ),
              )
            : Text(
                _controller.text,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17),
              ),
      ),
```

You can try using animated container for the smooth transition. Here I have provided you an example, you can adjust the animation duration too.